# SERVICE_OBJECT_SUPPLIER parameter is not specified error

Tags: java, spring, apache-axis

I have developed a webService using axis2 and spring. When I request the
 wsdl file from the webservice I get the right wsdl file, but when I want to
 use a defined operation of the webservice (using a java client),
I get the following exception:

```
[CODE]org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The SERVICE_OBJECT_SUPPLIER parameter is
not specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your services.xml file you need to define following two properties.

org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringServletContextObjectSupplier
 beanname-that-expose-as-a-WS

Take a look http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html